# signal slot custom struct issue

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I'm having problems emitting my own struct from a signal to a slot. The struct looks as following:

WorldObjectChange.h

```
#pragma once

    struct WorldObjectChange  {
        WorldObjectChange() {}
        ~WorldObjectChange() {}
        double x;
    };        
    Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(WorldObjectChange)
```

I called qRegisterMetaType to make the type known in the signal slot method

main.c

```
QApplication a(argc, argv); 
qRegisterMetaType<WorldObjectChange>();
```

The connection is queued since signal and slot inhabit different threads.
The connect happens in the constructor of a class that initializes and starts the thread for object1.

```
InitClass::InitClass(Object2 *object2) {
  Object1* object1 = new Object1();
  connect(object1, SIGNAL(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)), object2, SLOT(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)));
}
```

object1.h

```
#include "WorldObjectChange.h"

class object1 : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        object1();
    public signals:
        void updateObjects(WorldObjectChange);
};
```

object2.h

```
#include "WorldObjectChange.h"

class object2: public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit object2(QWidget * parent = 0);
    public slots:
        void updateObjects(WorldObjectChange worldChangeVector);
};
```

object2.cpp

```
void updateObjects(WorldObjectChange worldChangeVector) { }
```

The object seems to work fine in object1, but whenever I add the line for the slot in object 2 I get the following error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl
>   worldOutputGrid::updateObjects(struct WorldObjectChange)"
>   (?updateObjects@worldOutputGrid@@QEAAXUWorldObjectChange@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl
>   worldOutputGrid::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum
>   QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_static_metacall@worldOutputGrid@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Has function `object2::updateObjects()` a definition?

Comment: `WorldObjectChange` doesn't have members: `y`, `width`, or `height`. You've obviously gotta fix that to compile. If that solves your problem I can post it as an answer, but I think fixing that will help get us to the actual issues.

Comment: I forgot to delete the parameters and the  the definition in object2 exists. Changed it in the question

Comment: OK next question, where is the `connect` happening? You're not specifying the classes on the `updateObjects` so I'd assume that your signal and slot are both using either the signal or the slot's definition.

Comment: I've updated the question again

Comment: Linker error is indicating _worldOutputGrid_ namespace or class .. where is that in your code?

Comment: worldOutputGrid is object2

Answer (score 0):

[`connect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) takes a `QObject*` as it's 1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> arguments. In your code:

```
connect(object1, SIGNAL(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)), object2, SLOT(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)));
```

`object1` is not a `QObject*`. You need to use instead:

```
connect(&object1, SIGNAL(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)), object2, SLOT(updateObjects(WorldObjectChange)));
```

Comment: Sorry, when I edited the code I forgot that I'm using dynamic initilization. I changed it in the question.

Comment: @todayihateprogramming In that case this should work. There's something else afoot, to figure out what you'll need to actually build your toy example. Then you'll see there's no problem there. Next work backwards piecing in your stuff back in to see where your actual problem is.